# Regex to get Specific characters in a group wise array

Tags: regex

I am trying to get some pattern of characters in a group as an array, but the pattern has one issue like if I am giving first braces inside the characters then result is not coming like I need:

Below is the string:

```
DayValue([3],-2)+DayValue([5],-2)
```

the regex i tried:

```
const regex = /DayValue\((?!DayValue)(.*?)\)/gm;
```

Result1 I am getting:

```
 Match 1
Full match  0-16    DayValue([3],-2)
Group 1.    n/a [3],-2
Match 2
Full match  17-33   DayValue([5],-2)
Group 1.    n/a [5],-2
```

but for string :

```
 DayValue([3],(-2))+DayValue([5],(-2))
```

Result2 :

```
Match 1
Full match  0-17    DayValue([3],(-2)
Group 1.    n/a [3],(-2
Match 2
Full match  19-36   DayValue([5],(-2)
Group 1.    n/a [5],(-2
```

but I am expecting the same result as previous one i.e Result1

Could anybody help, Thanks.

Comment: The `.*?)\)` matches until the first occurrence of `)` which will match `(-2` I don't think you can skip the `(` if you want to keep a single group. Can you add a language tag to the question? Do you want to match balanced parenthesis?

Comment: Yes I want to match balance parenthesis

Comment: Can you add a language tag or the tool that you are using?